# What should be changed about this Xpath string to find the last child element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

A list of all child `div` elements are found when using the following line:

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="panel2LocListShell"]').find_elements_by_tag_name('div')`

However, when using Xpath to find the last child `div` element, there is a timeout error:

For example:

`WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@id = panel2LocListShell]/div[last()]')))`

What, if anything, should be changed about this Xpath line?: `'.//div[@id = panel2LocListShell]/div[last()]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="panel2LocListShell"]').find_elements_by_tag_name('div')`

Here, selenium would locate all `div` child elements *at any depth level* inside the `div` element with `id="panel2LocListShell"`.

> `.//div[@id = panel2LocListShell]/div[last()]`

In this case, you are looking for `div` elements located *directly under* the `div` element with `id="panel2LocListShell"`. Plus, the `panel2LocListShell` should be put into quotes.

Fixed expression:

```
.//div[@id = "panel2LocListShell"]//div[last()]
```

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like a manual sleep timeout is still needed despite fixing the xpath expression. Otherwise, the error "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" occurs when getting the full list of `div`'s after the WebDriverWait. Helpful answer nevertheless.